# How to search on-page with Internet Explorer in Windows 8 on a touch device?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, search, touchscreen

I neither have an external keyboard nor is the virtual keyboard available in the browser. As well, if I try to use the charms bar and choose "Search" in Internet Explorer, a new Bing tab is opened with the respective string.

So, how can I find a certain string on a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using IE11 desktop, `Gear icon > File > Find on page` should show you the text search box. To bring up the keyboard press the keyboard icon near the notification area (system tray):

[image: 1]

If you're using IE11 Modern, `Swipe up from bottom > Spanner icon > Find on page` will do the same. Touching the box will automatically bring up the on-screen keyboard in this case.